# How can I get rid of the 2nd navigation bar? They are directly on top of one another

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, constraints, navigationbar

[image]

click the link to view the image

There is something above the navigationbar, and I'm confused on what it is and how to get rid of it.

here is my tabController code

```
    {import UIKit
class TabBarController: UITabBarController, UITabBarControllerDelegate {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        delegate = self
        authenticateUserAndConfigureView()
    }
    func setupViewControllers() {
        let home = templateNavController(viewController: DiscoverViewController(), image: UIImage(named: "house")!, title: "Home")
        let search = templateNavController(viewController: SearchViewController(), image: UIImage(named: "search")!, title: "Discover")
        let problem = templateNavController(viewController: NewProblemViewController(), image: UIImage(named:"addproblem")!, title: "Add New Problem")
        let chat = templateNavController(viewController: MessageViewController(), image: UIImage(named: "chat")!, title: "Chat")
        let profile = templateNavController(viewController: ProfileViewController(), image: UIImage(named: "profile")!, title: "Profile")
        self.viewControllers = [home, search, problem, chat, profile]
    }
    func authenticateUserAndConfigureView() {

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if Auth.auth().currentUser == nil {
                let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: LoggedOut())
                navController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
                self.present(navController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            } else {
                self.setupViewControllers()
            }
        }
    }
    func templateNavController(viewController:  UIViewController,  image: UIImage, title: String)  ->  UINavigationController {
        let navController  = UINavigationController(rootViewController: viewController)
        navController.tabBarItem.image = image
        navController.navigationBar.backgroundColor = .white
        navController.tabBarItem.title = title
        return navController
    }
}
}
```

Comment: you mean the status bar?

Comment: It looks like you have a navigation controller in a tab view but haven't set "under top bars" or something.  Can you provide more details on how you have set up your view hierarchy?

Comment: Yes, so its navigation controller -> tabBar Controller -> navigation Controller -> view controller. Whenever i add a property to the navigationbar there are two navigation bars on screen. I can only effect the bottom one.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use 'Debug View Hierarchy' xCode tool to see views hierarchy in a screen.

Just run the app on a simulator or device and click 'Debug View Hierarchy' when your screen is active.

Here you can rotate screen and see all active layers. Once you select a layer you can check it name and position in hierarchy on the left bar.

[image: debug view hirerarchy]

Comment: Thank you! i figured out that there is two UInavigation view controllers at different levels and both are showing one on top of the other. I have no idea how to fix it though

Answer (score 0):

Hey Guys I figured it out! My mistake was that I cast my original TabBarController as a UINavigationController before setting the view controllers on there. Thus there was a navigation bar from the mistake UINavController and another navigation bar from the navigation controller that I cast on each view controller.